# Align text under div img

Tags: html, css

Needing help on making the text float underneath the social icons in a `<div>` . Tried `float:right` , `display:block` and `text-align:right` but still no luck.

CSS:

```
.footerLeft {
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #33383b;
}

.footerLeft p {
  margin-left: 25px;
}
.footerLeft img {
  width: 175px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;

}
.footerRight {
  float:right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #33383b;
}
.footerRight img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}
ul#menu li {
    display:inline;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float:right;
}
.footerRight p {
  text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="footerLeft">
<img src="img/logo.png">
<p>Sharpturn Network&copy; 2016</p>
</div>
<div class="footerRight">
<ul id="menu">
  <li><img src="img/footer/facebook.png"></li>
  <li><img src="img/footer/twitter.png"></li>
  <li><img src="img/footer/youtube.png"></li>
</ul><br>
<p>Designed by <blank></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/3arpsrht/)

What I've done in the fiddle is that, removed all the floats from your CSS and changed them to `inline-block`displays which made them really look like floated elements and then to align them to the right, I used `text-align:right`.

**Updated CSS**

```
ul#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  /* float:right; */
}

.footerRight p {
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
}

ul#menu {
  text-align: right;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Since, you have many media queries written, I would suggest you to change the CSS for `ul#menu li` as follows

```
ul#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Lal this is how it showed on the website, however it looks how I wanted it on the fiddle
http://imgur.com/rhw7fkK

Comment: No way...here is the [fullscreen fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/3arpsrht/show/) ..you can see that it works there too..that means you missed out some CSS while you copied..Just check it once more..

Comment: to view it via a website, I have put it on my website for you
http://www.sharpturnnetwork.com/v2/

Comment: Ok that was because, you had media css written and in the media css `@media only screen and (min-width: 769px)
li` you had a `float:left` which was causing the issue. try removing that.

Comment: Thank you very much @Lal - that worked a treat, thank you so much :)
Quick question, How would I make it responsive to a max-width: 321px?

Comment: Oh great..gad that it helped you.. :) ..But for that quick question I need more details of the problem. It would be better if you post it as a new question..